# Morse coding in C++ / Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

Good Morning everyone ! So I wanted to make a program that transmits light in Morse code and a receiver translates it into Arduino.

To get a visual rendering I chose to put an LED and a Buzzer. But when I download the program, the LED lights up and so does the Buzzer, and the LDR doesn't even translate what the transmitter sends it.

So this is the receiver code :

```
//Morse Code Binary Tree
//  Left child at 2n+1
// Right child at 2n+2
//         <.|->
//      .E       -T
//    .I  -A   .N  -M
//
const char MorseTree[] = {'\0','E', 'T', 'I', 'A', 'N', 'M', 'S',
                          'U', 'R', 'W', 'D', 'K', 'G', 'O', 'H',
                          'V', 'F', 'U', 'L', 'A', 'P', 'J', 'B',
                          'X', 'C', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q', '\0','\0','5',
                          '4', '\0','3', '\0','\0','\0','2', '\0',
                          '\0','+', '\0','\0','\0','\0','1', '6',
                          '=', '/', '\0','\0','\0','(', '\0','7',
                          '\0','\0','\0','8', '\0','9', '0', '\0',
                          '\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0',
                          '\0','\0','\0','?', '_', '\0','\0','\0',
                          '\0','"', '\0','\0','.', '\0','\0','\0',
                          '\0','@', '\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0',
                          '-', '\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0',
                          '\0',';', '!', '\0',')', '\0','\0','\0',
                          '\0','\0',',', '\0','\0','\0','\0',':',
                          '\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'
                         };


int val = 0; // A Variable to Store the Light Value from the LDR
int ctrHigh = 0;
int ctrLow = 0;
int codePtr = 0;
int dotLen = 400;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);// Start a Serial Connection
  Serial.print(codePtr);
}

void loop()
{
  val = analogRead(4);
  if (val >= 10)
  {
    ctrHigh++;
    ctrLow = 0;
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    tone(9, 100);
  } else {
    ctrLow++;
    if ((ctrHigh >= dotLen) && (ctrHigh < dotLen*2)) {
      Serial.print(".");
      codePtr = (2*codePtr) + 1;
    } else if (ctrHigh >= dotLen * 2) {
      Serial.print("-");
      codePtr = (2*codePtr) + 2;
    } else {
      if(ctrLow == dotLen*2){
        Serial.print(MorseTree[codePtr]);
        codePtr = 0;
      }
    }

    ctrHigh = 0;
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    noTone(9);
  }
}
```

this code is not long but it seemed fine to me, so I don't see the problem

and this is the picture of my editing.
[Morse Receiver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1HGj.png)

Comment: What is this analogRead? What is it supposed to indicate? Analog inputs are noisy, so I don't  see how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's supposed to read the information from the LDR,  put the photo of the montage in there.

Comment: I don't even know why the led and the buzzer turn on

Comment: How about simplifying it by removing the input and hardcoding it and removing one of the output methods? Then if the problem persists it will be easier to understand what it is and debug.

Comment: That loop will happen as quickly as it can, the high count will be very high

Comment: How can I do that? @EugeneSh.

Comment: What do you mean ? @ThomasJager

Comment: @Kiri You don't have any delay in your `loop` function, and every time it goes through the loop, you'll increment `ctrHigh` if you enter that part of the if. You probably want a delay somewhere.

Comment: No, you're not coding in C. You're coding in **C++**

Comment: @ThomasJager I don't understand why a delay will be usefull because I want to increment crtHigh, maybe I don't know what you want to tell me.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala oops my bad sorry

Comment: @Kiri Do you know how often `ctrHigh` will be incremented?

Comment: @ThomasJager until the signal is over?

Comment: @Kiri How often, not for how long